# Powershell escaping quotation marks in a variable that is used in another variable

Tags: powershell, escaping, quoting

I've found plenty of post explaining how to literally escape both single and double quotation marks using either `""""` for one double quotation mark, or `''''` for a single quotation mark (or just doing `` `" ``). I find myself in a situation where I need to search through a list of names that is input in a different query:

```
Foreach($Username in $AllMyUsers.Username){

    $Filter = "User = '$Username'"
    # do some more code here using $Filter

}
```

The problem occurs when I reach a username like O'toole or O'brian which contains quotation marks. If the string is literal I could escape it with

```
O`'toole
O''brian
etc.
```

But, since it's in a loop I need to escape the quotation mark for each user.

I tried to use `[regex]::Escape()` but that doesn't escape quotation marks.
I could probably do something like `$Username.Replace("'","''")` but it feels like there should be a more generic solution than having to manually escape the quotation marks. In other circumstances I might need to escape both single and double, and just tacking on .Replace like so `$VariableName.Replace("'","''").Replace('"','""')` doesn't feel like it's the most efficient way to code.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**: This feels exactly like a "how can I avoid SQL injection?" question but for handling strings in Powershell. I guess I'm looking for something like mysqli_real_escape_string but for Powershell.

Comment: What will you be using `$Filter` for? `''` is a valid escape sequence for a literal `'` _in PowerShell_, but not in WQL for example.

Comment: More specifically it is a DataTable and I will use .RowFilter. I found a blogpost saying "just use the .Replace" but it felt like a dirty trick and only works for that particular escape. I mean that workaround still works, I'm just not happy with it haha :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I could probably do something like `$Username.Replace("'","''")` but it feels like there should be a more generic solution than having to manually escape the quotation marks

As implied by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)'s comment, there is no *generic* solution, given that you're dealing with an *embedded* `'...'` string, and the escaping requirements entirely depend on the ultimate target API or utility - which is unlikely to be PowerShell itself (where `'` inside a `'...'` string must be *doubled*, i.e. represented as `''`).

In the case at hand, where you're passing the filter string to a [`System.Data.DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataTable)'s `.DataView`'s `.RowFilter` property, [`''` is required as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression#user-defined-values).

The conceptually cleanest way to handle the required escaping is to use `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), combined with a separate string-replacement operation:

```
$Filter = "User = '{0}'" -f ($UserName -replace "'", "''")
```

Note how PowerShell's [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) - rather than the .NET `[string]` type's `.Replace()` *method* - is used to perform the replacement.

Aside from being more PowerShell-idiomatic (with respect to: syntax, being case-*insensitive* by default, accepting *arrays* as input, converting to strings on demand), `-replace` is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based, which also makes performing *multiple* replacements easier.

To demonstrate with your hypothetical `.Replace("'","''").Replace('"','""')` example:

```
@'
I'm "fine".
'@ -replace '[''"]', '$0$0'
```

Output:

```
I''m ""fine"".
```